# How would I send an email to myself if the user's manager field is empty in AD?

Tags: powershell

Hello I am new to PowerShell and I am trying to figure out how to send emails to user's manager. In the script below I am able to send the notification if in AD ,manager field is not empty, but when is black I get an error message. How do I make it where it sends an email to myself, if the user's manager is blank? For some reason when I run this code, I keep getting line 233 manager email is null.

code is located here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731370/18947133

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$mailprops = @{
from = "test@domainname.com
smtpserver = "server.domain.com"
bodayashtml =$true


}
$startDate = Get-Date
$enddate= $startdate.addDays(x)

$props = @{ filer = "Account expirationDate -gt '$startdate' - and AccountExpiratioDate -lt '$endDate'"
```

Properties ='Accountexpirationdate', 'Manager' }

```
$Users = Get-ADuser @props
$bodyScriptBlock = {
# Group all users by their Manager
```

$Users | Group-Object Manager | ForEach-Object {

```
# Get this Manager's email address
$managerEmail = (Get-ADUser $_.Name -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress

# Create a string[] with the user's Name and their Account's Expiration Date
$userList = foreach($user in $_.Group)
{
    '- {0} expires on {1}' -f $user.Name, $user.AccountExpirationDate
}

# Execute the Body scriptblock passing this user's list
$body = & $bodyScriptBlock -UserList $userList

# Set the remaing values for Mail props
$mailProps.To = $managerEmail
$mailProps.Subject = "Account Expiration Notification for Managees" # ??? No idea what to put here
$mailProps.Body = $body

# Send the email with the list of users
Send-MailMessage @mailProps
```

Comment: here is my script:

Comment: Don't try and copy a script in a comment because that becomes unreadable. Instead, [edit] your question and paste it in there as formatted text

Comment: would that work?

Comment: Here’s a link for the markdown editing help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. But I believe there might be some buttons to distinguish code from text. Remember to omit any credentials and real e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
if ($null -eq $ManagerEmail)
   {$ManagerEmail = "yourEmail@domain.com"}
```

Comment: where would i put that on the script?

Comment: After this line: $managerEmail = (Get-ADUser $_.Name -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress

Comment: It worked, but I keep getting this error messages:

At line:23 char:23
+ $Manager = Get-ADUser $user.Manager -Properties DisplayName

Comment: and...
At line:232 char:33
$ManagerEmail = (Get-ADUser $_.Name -Properties EmailAddress).Ema ...

Comment: for some reason is not sending the email to me

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.